# How to trigger "Save as Offline" Chrome Feature using JavaScript or onlick?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web-scraping

I have a simple html page, and want to give the visitors a button where, on clicking downloads the html or mhtml version of webpage. So, that users can view page offline.

I tried implementing "save as html" code but it messes up my js, css and html. However, chrome builtin, download button works cool.

How to trigger 'save offline' feature using button click? Or download the page as mhtml directly?

My visitors are ignorant students, so not everyone knows that feature exists on chrome. So, want to implement it on the page.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should work as long as the page is being served through a web server, rather than a `file://` URL. The `btn` variable should be changed to whatever element you're using:

```js
const btn = document.getElementById('download');
btn.addEventListener('click', async () => {
    const resp = await fetch(location.href);
    if (resp.ok) {
        const blob = await resp.blob();
        const link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        link.download = document.title;
        link.click();
        setTimeout(() => URL.revokeObjectURL(link.href), 7000);
    } else {
        alert('Error downloading webpage');
    }
});
```

This works by first `fetch()`ing the current page's contents, then creating an [object URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) of the result. Then it creates a hidden `<a>` tag whose `.href` is set to the object URL, so when the `<a>`. tag is clicked, the object URL will be downloaded. I also set the [`.download`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAnchorElement/download) property, which specifies the filename of the downloaded file, to the current page's title. Finally, the hidden `<a>` tag is clicked and the object is revoked to cleanup memory.

You can also hide the download button if the site is being viewed as a downloaded file with this code:

```js
if (location.protocol == 'file:') {
    btn.style.display = 'none';
}
```

Comment: If you want that download to work offline, you'd need to convert `<link>` to `<style>` and inline `<script>` tags as well. This isn't quite the same thing as Chrome's builtin "save as html"

Comment: Hi Sir, I am too novice. Please add this with html code so I can call it understand implementing it. Really sorry for being noob.

Comment: Thank you so much Micheal. You are literally the life saver. Thank you very much. Happy coding ! Happy Sharing!

Comment: Hi, It seems like I need 15 Reputation to cast a vote!.

Comment: How does this work? Does downloading the `document.title` trigger the `save as` functionality?`

Comment: @Connor This works by creating a `fetch()` call to get the current page's content, then creating and clicking a hidden `<a>` tag with a `.href` of an object URL with `fetch()`'s result. The `.download` property sets the filename of the download (see [this MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAnchorElement/download)) to the current page's title.

Comment: @Connor I've edited my answer to include this explanation. This is an old answer, so thanks for prompting me to add an explanation!